# Unclose window in Firefox 57

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

How can you un-close a window in Firefox?

*Undo close-tab* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) only works within a window (which is different to Chrome).

I've come back to Firefox with the fantastic version 57 and want to know how to *Undo close-window*.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox 57 binds *Undo close-window* to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

It's more flexible but requires more understanding from the user than Chrome's approach of having a single *Undo close* command that works backwards through tabs and windows equally.

One issue here is that searching for this turns up results for earlier versions of Firefox that showed *Recently closed* items in the history view. In Firefox 57 the history view doesn't seem to have this feature any more. I don't know of a way other than this shortcut.